# Is there any way to distinguish if user adding new data to database or just changing old data in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have restriction in models.py that some tables can't have more then N rows, so I check it before saving data, but it also display error when the table is full, but I try to change some rows.

Is there any way to distinguish if user adding new data to database or just changing old data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` method is called both when an object is created and when it is updated.

However, when an object is being created, the `pk` of the object is `None` until `save` finishes. So what you can do is overwriting the `save` method of your models and check whether the object being saved has a `pk` set to `None`.

Namely

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk == None:
        # this object is being created
    else:
        # this object is being updated
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I have the same idea just 15 minutes after posting question :) sometimes I have to think twice before asking :)))